# Matrix as function manipulation

Tags: matrix, warning-messages, assignment

Consider matrix

```
mat[x_] := {{1, 2}, {3, x}}
```

with

```
mat[x][[1]]
```

giving

```
{1, 2}
```

I wanna do

```
mat[x][[1]] = 0;
```

but get error

```
"mat[x] in the part assignment is not a symbol"
```

How to do operation without error?

I wanna get

```
{{0, 0}, {3, x}}
```

Comment: What matrix do you hope to have after the operation?

Comment: @Marius I hope have {{0, 0}, {3, x}}

Comment: mat[x][[1,1]] is the first element of 1st row, mat[x][[1,2]] the 2nd of 1st row, mat[x][[2,1]] etc... but you have defined your function, so why don't you define a new one?

Comment: `ReplacePart[mat[x], 1 -> {0, 0}]`

Comment: To extend @Bob's solution: `DownValues[mat] = Fold[MapAt[#2, #1, {1, 2}] &, DownValues[mat], {ReplacePart[#, 1 -> {0, 0}] &, Evaluate}];`